# Dapper not returning selected/desired rows

Tags: c#, dapper

I am a newbie with Dapper and I  copied this SQL Script(from a test that I was doing with Entity Framework) and tried to return a List of theses rows, but its returning the entire Class and not just the ones that I want!

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-CD2UQI5\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ServerContext;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            var res = connection.Query<Table>("select Images,AddressFrom, from Table where Table.id = 1").ToList();
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, res);
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: What you mean by _entire Class_?

Comment: the query shown is not valid... so I'm 100% sure that isn't indicative code that actually shows the problem, because that could will just throw a `SqlException` (from the database server, nothing to do with dapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper doesn't do any processing of your SQL (well, it *does* in some very very limited scenarios). So: whatever is being returned is because of *your query* - it isn't changing the query to remove the `where` clause, and it isn't inventing data.

If you mean it is returning more columns than you expect, then again: check your query. The one shown in the question isn't valid (trailing comma in the `select`), so I can't really comment based on the question. Check for a rogue `*`.

So: take you query, and try running it SSMS or another SQL tool; see which rows and columns come back.

If `Table.id` is a unique / primary / identity / etc, then yes it seems odd to get more than one, but: I can't tell what is going on from here, except: dapper is simply running your query.

Minor points:

- `AsList()` would be preferable to `ToList()`
- if you expect exactly one or at most one result, there are methods to do that more efficiently - `QuerySingle` etc
- if the `id` isn't fixed, you probably want to use a parameter, for example:

  ```
  int id = ...
  var res = connection.Query<Table>(
      "select Images,AddressFrom, from Table where Table.id = @id", new { id }
  ).AsList();
  ```

Comment: I figure whats the problem is, I was still using the EntityFramework Class to `Query<Table>`. Regardless to the sql script, was just a partial code, just to see what could be wrong since I said that, I was making the same query on SQL server! Thanks!